# Retrieve custom fields from child of a child model in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve custom fields from a model using the `with()` statement in Laravel. When I just get all fields the child object comes ok, but when I try to retrieve just some fields of this child abject it returns to me the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

below I'll show how I'm doing these queries.

**When I execute the following query it works:**

```
 $cfps = CallForPaper::select('id', 'speech_id')->with([
            'speech:id,title,description',
            'speech.speakers'
         ])->get();
```

But when I execute the code below it returns the error which I have mentioned above.

```
$cfps = CallForPaper::select('id', 'speech_id')->with([
            'speech:id,title,description',
            'speech.speakers:id,name,email'
         ])->get();
```

**Note:** than only modification in this code is the line: `'speech.speakers:id,name,email'`

in my model **Speech**, the *`speakers`* relationship is the following:

```
public function speakers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Speaker::class, 'speech_speaker');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define the table_name for the id's your are selecting:

```
$cfps = CallForPaper::select('id', 'speech_id')->with([
    'speech:TABLE_NAME.id,title,description',
    'speech.speakers:TABLE_NAME.id,name,email'
])->get();
```

you can also do the following, ie. rename the id:

```
$cfps = CallForPaper::select('id', 'speech_id')->with([
   'speech:TABLE_NAME.id as speechID,title,description',
   'speech.speakers:TABLE_NAME.id as speakerID,name,email'
])->get();
```

Comment: God Save Leon!

Thanks so much guy! <3